# How to make an update view handle both an object creation first and the after that object updation in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am making a dating site and right now I am stuck in a problem.
The problem follows :

1.I want the user to create his user profile info like when his likes ,dislikes etc..

2.After the user has created his profile I want him to update that profile on that same page it was created.

3.The problem is how can i make my update view handle both user creation and user updation.For e.g If the user first created his profile then it will be done with create view and then when he has to update his profile it will be done with update so how can these two views be in same view.

Here's the views.py

```
  @login_required
 def profile(request,pk):
  user_detail = UserDetail.objects.all()
  return render(request,'social_app/profile.html'{'user_detail':user_detail,})


class Create_View(CreateView):
 model = UserDetail
 template_name = 'social_app/profile-create.html'
 fields = [

         'enthicity','You_work_as','image','cover_image','country','height',
        'birth_date','smoking','relationship','looking_for','diet','kids','eye_color',
        'status','hobby',

        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreateView` and `UpdateView` user different Ancestors so you'll need different CBVs for them (I think).  also, to update a record you're going to need to pull get it with a `pk` or something, whereas you won't with a `CreateView`

So have both a `CreateView` and `UpdateView` then pass with your context to the html file which you want to call.

Comment: It is possible to combine them, but not worth it in my experience.  You can of course have them use the same template, form, etc.

Comment: I know that but they are going to be on different urls